# how to show record from null column

Tags: sqlite

I have to use from sqlite DB and I insert many data in my sqlite file. now I want execute records that has "NULL". in oder word I want to see records that are "NULL".
when I execute this code I nothing get.

```
    select  * from table1 where ParentID = NULL 
   //or this select  * from table1 where ParentID = 'NULL'
```

this is my sqlite file :

[image]

I want execute folder1 with checking ParentID (I need only check ParentID column)

Answer (score 6):

`NULL` is never equal to anything, including `NULL`. You need to use `IS` instead.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ParentID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the following:

```
select  * from table1 where ParentID is NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` values represent missing unknown data.By default, a table column can hold NULL values.NULL values are treated differently from other values.

```
 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ParentID IS NULL
```

### Always use IS NULL to look for NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `IS NULL`. (The comparison operators `=` and `<>` both give UNKNOWN with NULL on either side of the expression.)

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ParentID IS NULL;
```